# Grafana - Slack alert doesn't show images

Tags: slack, grafana, slack-api

Following on from the documentation and answers to similar questions here, I've created a Slack app with a bot user and connected it to my public channel in Slack. I've also invited the bot user and gave it `files:write:user` OAuth Scope. After all this, I reinstalled the app to apply the changes.

My configuration in Grafana has:

- Include image ticked
- The correct webhook URL from Slack
- Recipient contains my channel name
- My bot token

The Send Test works fine, even in private channels. I first receive a notification from the app and then a pretty image from the bot user. From the Javascript console, my Grafana version is `5.0.3`. I've repeated this process several times with no luck. The only I can imagine is that I'm not an Admin but then I wouldn't have expected the test to work.

I've also looked through the Grafana log files and it seems to come from Grafana's side; specifically, it has trouble rendering the image.

```
lvl=info msg="New state change" logger=alerting.resultHandler alertId=1 newState=ok prev state=alerting
lvl=info msg=Rendering logger=png-renderer path="somepath?panelId=11111"
lvl=eror msg="failed to render an image" logger=png-renderer error="exit status 127"
lvl=info msg=uploaded logger=alerting.notifier url=
lvl=info msg="Executing slack notification" logger=alerting.notifier.slack ruleId=6 notification="myalert"
lvl=info msg="Uploading to slack via file.upload API" logger=alerting.notifier.slack
lvl=info msg="Request Completed" logger=context userId=1111 orgId=1111 uname= method=GET path=/ status=302 remote_addr=000.111.222.333 time_ms=0 size=29 referer=
```

Comment: I had this problem and decided to build a simple solution: https://www.grafanaforslack.com/

Answer (score 1):

Answering after long time, but I hope if this can be helpful to someone, To upload images on slack bot from Grafana, set files:write in Oauth and permission setting on app in slack setting(as stated in question than in particular channel invite your bot( try typing @botname it will automatically ask that invite bot to this channel)

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to install missing fonts, specifically `libfontconfig` in Ubuntu, if you are using the tar.gz file rather than the deb file (for some reason, it doesn't include the fonts by default). As a note to future users of other distros, each one has their own requirements so be sure to check out the Grafana docs.